# Make Org-Agenda and Orgzly show repeated events?

Tags: org-agenda, events

## Motivation

I want to organize my whole life with org-mode. In particular, I want my org-agenda to remind me when I need to work, since I have weird working times.

## My approach

My approach was to create an entry as follows:

```
* TODO Work at Foo

  <2021-07-19 Mon 09:00-16:00 +1w>
  <2021-07-20 Tue 09:30-13:30 +1w>
  <2021-07-21 Wed 09:00-16:00 +1w>
  <2021-07-22 Thu 09:30-13.30 +1w>
```

(I.e. I created plain timestamps which are meant for events.) (Note that the first dates of these events are already in the past.)

But this approach does not work as intended: 1. In GNU Emacs, the `org-agenda-list` command lists my working hours only on the first dates. 2. In Orgzly, with an agenda-search, the working hours aren't listed at all. (I guess because they are thought to be in the past.)

## Question

So how can I create an entry in my org-file so that GNU Emacs' org-agenda as well as Orgzly remind my of today's occurrences and the upcoming occurrences of a certain repeated task?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe in Emacs (I don't use Orgzly, so I cannot say  anything about it). What is shown in the agenda list depends on the agenda length:  for a weekly agenda starting on Monday and ending the next Sunday, only the dates of that week are shown. If you change it to e.g. a fortnightly agenda with `v t`, you get next week's dates as well. Or you can move forward one week in the weekly agenda with `f`. Either way, your item is visible on the correct dates.

Comment: You are right! I was really confused and maybe I had screwed up my Emacs configuration temporarily. Thank you for clarifying. -- It indeed seems to be an Orgzly-only bug.